# rails default_scope throws exception: undefined method abstract_class? for Object:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, default-scope

I would like to apply logical delete in my application(Instead of permanently deleting a record just have been marked as deleted). I have Added *available* column to all tables with default value **true**.
Now I want common place to write the following code for all models.

```
1) Write the instance method which make 'available' column value false when user clicks on destroy link.
2) Merge the 'available=true' condition to all ActiveRecord's queries while fetching the records.
```

With reference [Rails extending ActiveRecord::Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase),
I decided to use monkey patch to do above. Created monkey patch file in config/initializer/active_record_patch.rb:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
   def inactive
      update_attribute(:available, false)
   end

   default_scope :available => true
end
```

Getting following error when add the default_scope

**/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1212:in `class_of_active_record_descendant': undefined method`abstract_class?' for Object:Class (NoMethodError)**

Comment: Please help me to add the default_scope in some other way for all the models

Answer (score 1):

Try `default_scope where(:available => true)`.

Comment: Can you give any information about the error you got? For what it's worth, the ActiveRecord docs say you should format as I showed (check the `ActiveRecord::Scoping::Default::ClassMethods` docs).

Answer (score 0):

I believe monkeypatching `ActiveRecord::Base` is not the way to go. Maybe you should try to create a module that when included/extended in your models, create this functionalities seamlessly.

Comment: I have tried modules, but i got the error NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for MyModule:Module