# Rails abstract custom destroy method (or add exception to model errors by default)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

What I am trying to do is return an error, instead of an exception, when a particular model cannot be destroyed. Currently, it raises `ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError`, but that is not returned to a flash message, or added to the errors collection of the model.

What I have done is setup this in my resourceful controller:

```
  def destroy
    begin
      resource.destroy
    rescue ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError => e
      resource.errors.add(:base, e)
    end
  end
```

I'd rather not manage this within every single controller which requires this particular behavior. How can I abstract it? I can't see it being a good idea to overwrite the destroy method for `ActiveRecord::Base`, but maybe there won't be any gotchas?

I'm using inherited_resources gem, so perhaps there is a way to answer this by extending that?

One other idea I had was to extend `ActiveRecord::Base` using `ActiveSupport::Concern` (from here: [Rails extending ActiveRecord::Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase)) and then delegate the destroy method to a custom destroy on a model-to-model basis. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was inheriting my controllers from a master resources controller, which I've found to be much cleaner and powerful than the other options discussed (found here: http://roberto.peakhut.com/2010/09/27/admin-controllers-with-inherited-resources/).

```
// controllers/resources_controller.rb
class ResourcesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  inherit_resources

  def destroy
    begin
      resource.destroy
    rescue ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError => e
      resource.errors.add(:base, e)
    end
  end
end
```

Then, simply inherit your resourceful controllers from this controller instead of ApplicationController:

```
// controllers/models_controller.rb
class ModelsController < ResourcesController

end
```

Hope that helps somebody in a similar situation.

Answer (score 2):

First I will say I agree with the attitude of not overriding ActiveRecord::Base methods like destroy. In order to DRY this behavior you have several options, I'll list two of them:

The first - Instead of writing the rescue clause in the specific controller you can embed it into your ApplicationController so the behavior will be application-wide:

```
# ApplicationController.rb

rescue_from ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError do |exception|
  resource.errors.add(:base, exception) if resource
end
```

Another option would be to make a module and include it in the different controllers you want to have this behavoir:

```
module SafeDestroyer
  def safe_destroy(resource)
   begin
      resource.destroy
    rescue ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError => e
      resource.errors.add(:base, e)
    end
  end
end

class MyController < ApplicationController
  include SafeDestroyer

  def destroy
    safe_destroy(resource)
  end

end
```

Comment: I much prefer the first option. Second seems to require the same unnecessary definitions with the actual innards moved elsewhere. It appears I don't have access to 'resource' from within the application controller. I've included inherited_resources. Anything stand out as to why? The exception is being caught.

Comment: Found another option: http://roberto.peakhut.com/2010/09/27/admin-controllers-with-inherited-resources/ which is to inherit controllers from a custom 'resources controller' and define the custom behavior there.

Comment: About your first comment: Don't know why resource is not available for you on the rescue block... Maybe it is some implementation issue with InheritedResources which I don't know that well. The option of Inheriting from controllers is pretty similar to the option of including modules but of course it will also do the job. As I stated, there are many ways to keep you code DRY, I listed two of them. You should definitely use the one that best suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks Erez, I've gone with inheriting from a base resources controller as I can build on this and include custom methods for crud. Thanks for the other possibilities, you pointed me in the right direction.