# Understanding Ruby on Rails send(:include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to develop a [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) Plugin, I started reading the [documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial), and learning a lot of Ruby and a lot of Ruby on Rails. (I'm a PHP/Python/js guy)

Then I started looking through other plugins, and I found [this code](https://github.com/9thport/redmine_extend_permissions/blob/master/init.rb). I can't find enough information to fully understand how this line of code works:

```
Issue.send(:include, RedmineRequireIssueAllowedToChangeAssignee::Patches::IssuePatch)
```

I understand that inside IssuePatch are some things to override or add to Issue class.

Then I [found this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send), explaining the use of send, and that confuses me, why not use just Issue.include?

The main question would be: where is this method `include` defined and what does it does?

UPDATE: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase/2330533#2330533)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't just do `include` because it's a private method, so you use `send` which circumvents ruby visibility control. With `send` you can call any method, even private ones (as in this case).

> where is this method include defined and what does it does?

It's defined as [Module#include](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-include) and, when invoked with a module as a parameter, it appends all instance methods of that module to the receiver (which is, in your case, `Issue` class). It's a very-very common idiom in Ruby.

Comment: what happens if an instance method in the receiver is defined using the same name in the module passed as parameter?

Comment: Class' own method will take precendce, and method from the module will be available as `super`. See [example](http://pastie.org/5423811).

Comment: Perfect, great answer. If you want, add the example in the answer. Thanks!