# Implementing Abstract Base Model Class, the Rails Way™

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, inheritance, abstract-class, sti

I have a **Book** and **Download** model that share many attributes, so my goal is to inherit the common attributes from a **DownloadableResource** model.
Had a look at [STI](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9780132480345/advanced-active-record/ch09lev1sec5), but I went the [abstract base model class](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9780132480345/advanced-active-record/ch09lev1sec6) way instead:

- models:

  ```
  class DownloadableResource < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true

    attr_accessible :title, :url, :description, :active, :position
    validates :title, :url, :description, presence: true
    scope :active, where(active: true).order(:position)
  end

  class Book < DownloadableResource
    attr_accessible :cover_url, :authors
    validates :cover_url, :authors, presence: true
  end

  class Download < DownloadableResource
    attr_accessible :icon_url
    validates :icon_url, presence: true
  end
  ```
- migrations:

  ```
  class CreateDownloadableResources < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :downloadable_resources do |t|
        t.string    :title
        t.string    :url
        t.text      :description
        t.boolean   :active,      default: false
        t.integer   :position
        t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end

  class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :books do |t|
        t.string :cover_url
        t.string :authors
        t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end

  class CreateDownloads < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :downloads do |t|
        t.string :icon_url
        t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end
  ```

After migration, when I create a new Book the result is far from expected:

```
> Book.new
=> #<Book id: nil, cover_url: nil, authors: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Can somebody please shed some light on how to implement the Abstract Base Model Class technique so ActiveRecord models can share common code via [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2330533/341929) yet be persisted to different database tables?

Comment: One way is a composition instead of inheritance. Some example: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/17-extract-into-module

Comment: As a side note, even if you go with two similarly structured tables, you can at least keep your migrations DRY by first creating all tables with only their unique fields and then doing something like
`[:books, :downloads].each do |table|
    change_table table do |t|
      t.text :description
      # ...
    end
end`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By declaring a model as abstract you are actually saying that there's no underlying table and you want to allow subclassing. That means:

- You don't need the `downloadable_resources` table
- Book.table_name prints `books` instead of `downloadable_resources`

As @Finbarr already mentioned, this also means that both `Book` and `Download` models need to have all of the attributes in their tables.

What is this actually useful for then? In my opinion not for much. You can share validations, scopes etc. but you can achieve all of that more easily by including custom modules.

To solve your problem I would probably go with a different approach. I would create another model called `DownloadableContent` that would be self contained. It would include validations and the table would have all of the attributes. And finally models `Book` and `Download` would have a polymorphic `has_one` relation to the `DownloadableContent` model.

You could go with the STI approach but I generally don't like mixing all of the custom attributes together.

Answer (score 5):

There shouldn't be a `downloadable_resources` table in this case.  Both your books and downloads tables should declare all of the fields they need.

Comment: Why? What makes this case unsuited for inheritance? And how to decide when it's worth inheriting and when it's not?