# How do I add a model specific configuration option to a rails concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in the process of writing an Importable concern for my rails project. This concern will provide a generic way for me to import a csv file into any model that includes Importable.

I need a way for each model to specify which field the import code should use to find existing records. Are there any recommended ways of adding this type of configuring for a concern?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than including the concern in each model, I'd suggest creating an `ActiveRecord` submodule and extend `ActiveRecord::Base` with it, and then add a method in that submodule (say `include_importable`) that does the including. You can then pass the field name as an argument to that method, and in the method define an instance variable and accessor (say for example `importable_field`) to save the field name for reference in your `Importable` class and instance methods.

So something like this:

```
module Importable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ActiveRecord
    def include_importable(field_name)

      # create a reader on the class to access the field name
      class << self; attr_reader :importable_field; end
      @importable_field = field_name.to_s

      include Importable

      # do any other setup
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    # reference field name as self.importable_field
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    # reference field name as self.class.importable_field
  end

end
```

You'll then need to extend `ActiveRecord` with this module, say by putting this line in an initializer (`config/initializers/active_record.rb`):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.extend(Importable::ActiveRecord)
```

(If the concern is in your `config.autoload_paths` then you shouldn't need to require it here, see the comments below.)

Then in your models, you would include `Importable` like this:

```
class MyModel
  include_importable 'some_field'
end
```

And the `imported_field` reader will return the name of the field:

```
MyModel.imported_field
#=> 'some_field'
```

In your `InstanceMethods`, you can then set the value of the imported field in your instance methods by passing the name of the field to [`write_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write.html#method-i-write_attribute), and get the value using [`read_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read.html#method-i-read_attribute):

```
m = MyModel.new
m.write_attribute(m.class.imported_field, "some value")
m.some_field
#=> "some value"
m.read_attribute(m.class.importable_field)
#=> "some value"
```

Hope that helps. This is just my personal take on this, though, there are other ways to do it (and I'd be interested to hear about them too).

Comment: Great answer, thank you. It all makes sense. I'll try what you've suggested tomorrow and award the solution after that.

Comment: It's all working but I have one small issue. I get the following error unless I specifically require 'concerns/importable' at the top of each model file.

  NameError: undefined local variable or method `include_importable' for #<Class:0x007fc1bdb8dc20>

I've added the concerns directory to the autoload_path like so:

  config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]

It's not that big of an issue but I'd prefer not to have to require it  everywhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is the `ActiveRecord::Base.extend(Importable::ActiveRecord)` line, which has to be called *before* your models are loaded in order for ActiveRecord to have the `includes_importable` method. Autoloading doesn't work because the actual `Importable` module name is not mentioned in your model code. There are a few ways to solve the problem, I guess the easiest is to create an initializer at `config/initializers/active_record.rb` and move the `extend` line in there, with a `require 'concerns/importable'` at the top. Then you won't have to require it in your models.

Comment: For reference, see also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase

Comment: Actually, if you have the concern somewhere in `config.autload_paths` then you don't need the `require 'concerns/importable'` line in the initializer.

Comment: Updated my answer with the stuff discussed here.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529079/rails-passing-an-argument-to-a-concern

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900356/how-to-create-a-rails-4-concern-that-takes-an-argument

Comment: how do you include this in config.autoload_paths?

Answer (score 11):

A slightly more "vanilla-looking" solution, we do this (coincidentally, for the exactly some csv import issue) to avoid the need for passing arguments to the Concern.  I am sure there are pros and cons to the error-raising abstract method, but it keeps all the code in the app folder and the models where you expect to find it.

In the "concern" module, just the basics:

```
module CsvImportable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # concern methods, perhaps one that calls 
  #   some_method_that_differs_by_target_class() ...

  def some_method_that_differs_by_target_class()
    raise 'you must implement this in the target class'
  end

end
```

And in the model having the concern:

```
class Exemption < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CsvImportable

  # ...

private
  def some_method_that_differs_by_target_class
    # real implementation here
  end
end
```

Comment: i like this variant better, especially if the concern is app specific (not in a gem) and not included in a lot of other models.