# Passing arguments to a Concern, using in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, activesupport-concern

I have a Concern to set up some much used associations (among other things), but I need to make some small tweaks depending on the class where the concern is used. My basic concern looks like this:

````
module Organizable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :person_organizations

    has_many :organizations,
             through:     :person_organizations,
             class_name:  <STI CLASS NAME HERE>
  end
end
```
````

As you can see I want to be able to change the class name in the organizations association.

I was thinking I could include some class methods to provide this support, but I am unable to figure our how to proceed to fetch this value. Here is how I see myself using it:

```
class Dentist < Person
  include Organizable
  organizable organization_class: DentistClinic
end
```

And here is my current version of the code:

```
module Organizable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    attr_reader :organization_class

  private

    def organizable(organization_class:)
      @organization_class = organization_class
    end
  end

  included do
    has_many :person_organizations

    has_many :organizations,
             through:     :person_organizations,
             class_name:  self.class.organization_class.name
  end
end
```

I think there are at least two problems with this:

1) The `.organization_class` method doesn't seem to be defined at the time the association is set up, as I'm getting a `NoMethodError: undefined method`organization_class' for Class:Class` when I load the Dentist model.

2) I guess the association inside the concern will be evaluated before i even get to pass the class to the concern (the `organizable organization_class: DentistClinic` line), so it would not contain a value anyway.

I'm really unsure about how to get around this. Is there a way to pass this parameter into the concern and have the association set up using this value?

---

This is not a duplicate of [How to create a Rails 4 Concern that takes an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900356)

I'm *doing* pretty much exactly what's outlined in that post. My use case is different in that I'm trying to use the argument to configure an association which is defined inside the Concern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Rails 4 Concern that takes an argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900356/how-to-create-a-rails-4-concern-that-takes-an-argument)

Comment: No, it's not. As you can see from my question, I'm doing pretty much exactly what's outlined in that post. My use case is different in that I'm trying to use the argument to configure an association which is defined inside the Concern.

Answer (score 6):

I was having a similar problem where I needed to define a custom association inside a Concern based on a parameter from the Model itself.

The solution I found (tested in Rails 5.2 but other versions should be similar) is to define the relationship inside a class method, similar to the answer Mirza suggested.

Here is a example of the code,
The Concern:

```rb
require 'active_support/concern'

module Organizable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :person_organizations
  end

  class_methods do
    def organization_class_name(class_name)
      has_many :organizations,
            through: :person_organizations,
            class_name: class_name
    end
  end
end
```

The Model:

```rb
class Dentist < Person
  include Organizable
  organization_class_name DentistClinic
end
```

I also would prefer to do exactly as you suggested in your answer, is looks cleaner, but that required that class methods be evaluated and used before `included do`.

Basically what I needed was a way to use concern parameters in association definitions, and this is the most straight forward way to do it, I am leaving it here if someone needs it.

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be to include dynamic modules into the class.

```
module Organizable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def organizable(klass)
    Module.new do
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      included do
        has_many :person_organizations

        has_many :organizations,
                 through:     :person_organizations,
                 class_name:  klass
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Haven't tested it, but should work.

```
class Dentist < Person
  extend Organizable

  include organizable(DentistClinic)
end
```

Comment: great, thanks for this as it worked for my purposes. I do not believe you need, and did not use,  ActiveSupport::concern for the outer module however. I believe since you are just extending the target with a single class method it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
module Organizable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
   included do
     has_many :person_organizations
   end

   def organizable(class_name)  
     has_many :organizations, through: :person_organizations, class_name: class_name
   end
  end
end
```

And then:

```
class Dentist < Person
  include Organizable
  organizable DentistClinic
end
```