# ActiveRecord find_each combined with limit and order

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to run a query of about 50,000 records using ActiveRecord's `find_each` method, but it seems to be ignoring my other parameters like so:

```
Thing.active.order("created_at DESC").limit(50000).find_each {|t| puts t.id }
```

Instead of stopping at 50,000 I'd like and sorting by `created_at`, here's the resulting query that gets executed over the *entire* dataset:

```
Thing Load (198.8ms)  SELECT "things".* FROM "things" WHERE "things"."active" = 't' AND ("things"."id" > 373343) ORDER BY "things"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
```

Is there a way to get similar behavior to `find_each` but with a total max limit and respecting my sort criteria?

Comment: Any particular reason you haven't accepted any answers yet?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to :-\

Comment: In batch operation like find_each, find_in_batches scoped order and limit are ignored, it's forced to be batch order and batch size

Answer (score 76, accepted):

[The documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html) says that find_each and find_in_batches don't retain sort order and limit because:

- Sorting ASC on the PK is used to make the batch ordering work.
- Limit is used to control the batch sizes.

You could write your own version of this function like @rorra did. But you can get into trouble when mutating the objects. If for example you sort by created_at and save the object it might come up again in one of the next batches. Similarly you might skip objects because the order of results has changed when executing the query to get the next batch. Only use that solution with read only objects.

Now my primary concern was that I didn't want to load 30000+ objects into memory at once. My concern was not the execution time of the query itself. Therefore I used a solution that executes the original query but only caches the ID's. It then divides the array of ID's into chunks and queries/creates the objects per chunk. This way you can safely mutate the objects because the sort order is kept in memory.

Here is a minimal example similar to what I did:

```
batch_size = 512
ids = Thing.order('created_at DESC').pluck(:id) # Replace .order(:created_at) with your own scope
ids.each_slice(batch_size) do |chunk|
    Thing.find(chunk, :order => "field(id, #{chunk.join(',')})").each do |thing|
      # Do things with thing
    end
end
```

The trade-offs to this solution are:

- The complete query is executed to get the ID's
- An array of all the ID's is kept in memory
- Uses the MySQL specific FIELD() function

Hope this helps!

Comment: The 4.x documentation says limit is not supported. But the latest 5.x documentation does seem to honor limit.

Comment: Your answer is outdated now. Both limit and order are supported since 5.x and 6.1 respectively. Please update your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

[*find_each*](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each) uses [*find_in_batches*](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches) under the hood.

Its not possible to select the order of the records, as described in *find_in_batches*, is automatically set to ascending on the primary key (“id ASC”) to make the batch ordering work.

However, the criteria is applied, what you can do is:

```
Thing.active.find_each(batch_size: 50000) { |t| puts t.id }
```

Regarding the limit, it wasn't implemented yet:  https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5696

---

Answering to your second question, you can create the logic yourself:

```
total_records = 50000
batch = 1000
(0..(total_records - batch)).step(batch) do |i|
  puts Thing.active.order("created_at DESC").offset(i).limit(batch).to_sql
end
```

Comment: Is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: @jan-hettich, I wrote that *find_in_batches* doesn't support the *limit* option in my original answer, I also pointed to the pull request that implemented the option yet it was never accepted/merged.

Comment: This solution will get you into trouble if you are mutating the objects when processing the batches. You might either skip some or have doubles if the mutation has an effect on the sort order in the database.

Comment: @dirk-geurs Feel free to write a better solution to the question made.

Comment: This wont work because most of time you want to sort on something that will change during the batch size.

Comment: `total_records - batch` could be less than the `batch` size, which would be a negative range. I would call `abs` on the calculation to ensure at least one iteration of the results:

e.g. `(0..(total_records - batch).abs)`

Comment: In order to not miss the last batch when `total_records` is not a multiple of `batch` (and even when it is), your range should be `(0..(total_records - 1))`.

Comment: @BenSimpson is right, I used `(0..[(total_records - batch), total_records].max)`. But @Paused ... solves it better. Eg. `batch = 10` , `total_records=35` => `steps = [0,10,20]` and 31..35 is not covered.

Comment: I guess if we decrease then we might skip extra records that are out of the max bound. Shouldn't it be  (0..(records_size + batch_size)).step(batch_size) ?

Answer (score 23):

Retrieving the `ids` first and processing the `in_groups_of`

```
ordered_photo_ids = Photo.order(likes_count: :desc).pluck(:id)

ordered_photo_ids.in_groups_of(1000, false).each do |photo_ids|
  photos = Photo.order(likes_count: :desc).where(id: photo_ids)

  # ...
end
```

It's important to also add the `ORDER BY` query to the inner call.

Comment: Unlike the accepted answer, this works in PostgreSQL. Also, nice job keeping the answer succinct.

Comment: This is going to require plucking all the IDs for the table in one query, and I don't know if that's advisable for larger tables (which is where you'd be using find_in_batches anyway).

Comment: Although I guess for something like this you might have to resort to getting all the IDs if you need to sort by an arbitrary column.

Comment: @Darme - it really shouldn't be, since it pulls all IDs from the table into RAM. This is what the original question wants to avoid. There's a gigantic (unbounded) database query and unbounded RAM requirements for the ID array in Ruby, then it all has to be marshalled into the mother of all SQL queries when that ID list is quoted back to the database via `WHERE...IN`. It looks elegant but that's the risk sometimes with Ruby - you don't realise the impact sometimes. It's not as bad as full records, but even IDs will be heavy going with large tables.

Comment: @AndrewHodgkinson you're right: it seemed to work right at first but after a while I ran into this specific issue.

Comment: If you're using MySQL, the IDs are already in memory.. how can you fetch the IDs in batches from SQL, without having to store all IDs in memory at once?

Answer (score 7):

Rails 6.1 adds [support](https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/04/29/rails-support-descending-order-for-find-each-find-in-batches.html) for descending order in `find_each`, `find_in_batches` and `in_batches`.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to put an implementation tailored for your particular model into the model itself (speaking of which, `id` is usually a better choice for ordering records, `created_at` may have duplicates):

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_each_desc limit
    batch_size = 1000
    i = 1
    records = self.order(created_at: :desc).limit(batch_size)
    while records.any?
      records.each do |task|
        yield task, i
        i += 1
        return if i > limit
      end
      records = self.order(created_at: :desc).where('id < ?', records.last.id).limit(batch_size)
    end
  end
end
```

Or else you can generalize things a bit, and make it work for all the models:

`lib/active_record_extensions.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::Batches.module_eval do
  def find_each_desc limit
    batch_size = 1000
    i = 1
    records = self.order(id: :desc).limit(batch_size)
    while records.any?
      records.each do |task|
        yield task, i
        i += 1
        return if i > limit
      end
      records = self.order(id: :desc).where('id < ?', records.last.id).limit(batch_size)
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Querying.module_eval do
  delegate :find_each_desc, :to => :all
end
```

`config/initializers/extensions.rb`:

```
require "active_record_extensions"
```

P.S. I'm putting the code in files according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2329394/52499).

Comment: excelent approach this solved my issues for batching and sorting by updated_at date

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate backwards by standard ruby iterators:

```
Thing.last.id.step(0,-1000) do |i|
  Thing.where(id: (i-1000+1)..i).order('id DESC').each do |thing|
    #...
  end
end
```

Note: `+1` is because BETWEEN which will be in query includes both bounds but we need include only one.

Sure, with this approach there could be fetched less than 1000 records in batch because some of them are deleted already but this is ok in my case.

Answer (score 3):

As remarked by @Kirk in one of the comments, `find_each` supports `limit` as of version [5.1.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md#rails-510-april-27-2017).

Example from the changelog:

```
Post.limit(10_000).find_each do |post|
  # ...
end
```

The [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) says:

> Limits are honored, and if present there is no requirement for the batch size: it can be less than, equal to, or greater than the limit.

(setting a custom order is still not supported though)

Comment: Confirming it also works fine also in Rails 6+. Thanks for the tip @tsauerwein

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same behaviour and thought up of this solution. This DOES NOT order by created_at but I thought I would post anyways.

```
max_records_to_retrieve = 50000
last_index = Thing.count
start_index = [(last_index - max_records_to_retrieve), 0].max
Thing.active.find_each(:start => start_index) do |u|
    # do stuff
end
```

Drawbacks of this approach:
- You need 2 queries (first one should be fast)
- This guarantees a max of 50K records but if ids are skipped you will get less.

Comment: Since I found this while looking for skip + find_each, it's worth mentioning here: the :start option can be used as an equivalent to skip() that you might use otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can try **[ar-as-batches](https://github.com/telent/ar-as-batches)** Gem.

From their [documentation](http://ww.telent.net/2012/5/4/changing_sort_order_with_activerecord_find_in_batches) you can do something like this

```
Users.where(country_id: 44).order(:joined_at).offset(200).as_batches do |user|
  user.party_all_night!
end
```

Comment: doesn't look like it's available from ruby gems, but requiring it off github works great

Answer (score 0):

Using [Kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari) or something other it will be easy.

### Create batch loader class.

```
module BatchLoader
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def batch_by_page(options = {})
    options = init_batch_options!(options)

    next_page = 1

    loop do
      next_page = yield(next_page, options[:batch_size])

      break next_page if next_page.nil?
    end
  end

  private

  def default_batch_options
    {
      batch_size: 50
    }
  end

  def init_batch_options!(options)
    options ||= {}
    default_batch_options.merge!(options)
  end
end
```

### Create Repository

```
class ThingRepository
  include BatchLoader

  # @param [Integer] per_page
  # @param [Proc] block
  def batch_changes(per_page=100, &block)
    relation = Thing.active.order("created_at DESC")

    batch_by_page do |next_page|
      query = relation.page(next_page).per(per_page)
      yield query if block_given?
      query.next_page
    end
  end
end
```

### Use the repository

```
repo = ThingRepository.new
repo.batch_changes(5000).each do |g|
  g.each do |t|
    #...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding find_in_batches_with_order did solve my usecase, where I was having ids already but need batching and ordering. It was inspired by @dirk-geurs solution

```
# Create file config/initializers/find_in_batches_with_order.rb with follwing code.
ActiveRecord::Batches.class_eval do
  ## Only flat order structure is supported now
  ## example: [:forename, :surname] is supported but [:forename, {surname: :asc}] is not supported
  def find_in_batches_with_order(ids: nil, order: [], batch_size: 1000)
    relation = self
    arrangement = order.dup
    index = order.find_index(:id)

    unless index
      arrangement.push(:id)
      index = arrangement.length - 1
    end

    ids ||= relation.order(*arrangement).pluck(*arrangement).map{ |tupple| tupple[index] }
    ids.each_slice(batch_size) do |chunk_ids|
      chunk_relation = relation.where(id: chunk_ids).order(*order)
      yield(chunk_relation)
    end
  end
end
```

Leaving Gist here https://gist.github.com/the-spectator/28b1176f98cc2f66e870755bb2334545

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a query with `DISTINCT ON` where you need an `ORDER BY` with that field, so this is my approach with Postgres:

```
def filtered_model_ids
  Model.joins(:father_model)
       .select('DISTINCT ON (model.field) model.id')
       .order(:field)
       .map(&:id)
end

def processor
  filtered_model_ids.each_slice(BATCH_SIZE).lazy.each do |batch|
    Model.find(batch).each do |record|
      # Code
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My code

```
batch_size = 100
total_count = klass.count
offset = 0
processed_count = 0
while processed_count < total_count
  relation = klass.order({ active_at: :asc, created_at: :desc }).offset(offset).limit(batch_size)
  relation.each do |record|
    record.process
  end
  processed_count += batch_size
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Do it in one query and avoid iterating:

`User.offset(2).order('name DESC').last(3)`

will product a query like this

`SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 3], ["OFFSET", 2]`