# Ordered batches clear solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, batch-query

Given the following code in ruby/rails, block code is omitted.

```rb
Model.order(id: :desc).find_in_batches { |group| ... }
```

If you run this, you will get a warning.

`Scoped order and limit are ignored, it's forced to be batch order and batch size`

Of course we can use some custom boilerplate code to achieve this, but I wondering is there rails-way?

I have found [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/98a57aa5f610bc66af31af409c72173cdeeb3c9e/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb#L275), but I do not see the possibility to change it is behaviour. What if I don't need asc, but I need desc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches):

> NOTE: It’s not possible to set the order. That is automatically set to
>   ascending on the primary key (“id ASC”) to make the batch ordering
>   work. This also means that this method only works when the primary key
>   is orderable (e.g. an integer or string).

The reason it is deliberately limited to primary_key order because those values don't change. So if you mutate the data as you're traversing it you dont get repeated options back.

In case of `id: :desc` you will not get new records that were inserted after the transaction to get initial batch was started.

Refs

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2502-patch-arbase-reverse-find_in_batches

https://ww.telent.net/2012/5/4/changing_sort_order_with_activerecord_find_in_batches

[ActiveRecord find_each combined with limit and order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189937/activerecord-find-each-combined-with-limit-and-order)

Comment: Ok, with `order(updated_at: :desc)` it makes sense, but what about `id: :desc`, what problems can occur here? I don't quite understand. It's obvious about some order, where clauses, but simple ordering. Seems for me as it is some historical decision that lived through nowadays.

Comment: @zhisme Yes. It's foolproof conversion to not mess up with ordering. Of course if you know what you are doing you can bypass that by patching `as_batches`

Comment: @zhisme I think in case of `id: :desc` you will not get new records that were inserted after the transaction to get initial batch was started