# Turning extension of ActiveRecord in gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rubygems

This extension create `cache_find` method for all models of app (I've create this using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2329394/740394)).

config/active_record_extension.rb

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module ActiveRecordExtension

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # add your instance methods here
  def flush_find
    Rails.cache.delete([self.class.name, :cached_find, id])
  end

  included do
    after_commit :flush_find
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def cached_find id
      Rails.cache.fetch([self.name, :cached_find, id]) { self.find(id) }
    end
  end
end

# include the extension
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
```

I turned this code into a gem and added to this [repo](https://bitbucket.org/rodrigora/model_caching/src/).

So I want to add this methods dynamically, something like this:

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  # id, name, email, age...

  cached :find, :find_by_name, :find_by_email
end
```

and the above code should generate `cached_find`, `flush_find`, `cached_find_by_name`, `flush_find_by_name`... You get it.

I need help to:

1. Test `Rails.cache` methods in `model_caching` gem.
2. Create code to dynamically add methods to app models based on `cached` method arguments.

Some links that helped me but do not meet all:

https://github.com/radar/guides/blob/master/extending-active-record.md

http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html

**Fell free to clone and improve [gem code](https://bitbucket.org/rodrigora/model_caching/src/).**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to hack ActiveRecord::Base. You can add what Marc-Alexandre said right into your concern, like so:

```
module ActiveRecordExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  ...

  module ClassMethods
    def cached(*args)
      define_method "cached_#{arg.to_s}" do 
        # do whatever you want to do inside cached_xx
      end

      define_method "flush_#{arg.to_s}" do
        # do whatever you want to to inside flush_xx
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also, I would not auto include the extension directly in ActiveRecord, I think it's better to explicitly include it in the models you are going to use it.

Answer (score 1):

To add code dynamically you need to hack the ActiveRecord::Base class. In another file (you usually put in lib/core_ext) you could do as follow :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  def self.cached(*args)
    args.each do |arg|
      define_method "cached_#{arg.to_s}" do 
        # do whatever you want to do inside cached_xx
      end

      define_method "flush_#{arg.to_s}" do
        # do whatever you want to to inside flush_xx
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What it does basically is takes all your arguments for cached (:find, :find_by_name, etc) and define the two methods (cache_find, cache_find_by_name) and flush_find, .. etc)

Hope this helps !

Comment: Good. Now, I need to access Rails class inside `define_method` block. I have to add Rails dependency to `gemspec` file??

Comment: Since your gem is extending Rails, yes you should :)