# How to write tests for ActiveRecord extension gem

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rubygems, rspec2

I'm creating a Ruby gem that will extend the ActiveRecord functionality. I read the following Stack Overflow posts of how to extend ActiveRecord: [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215952/turning-extension-of-activerecord-in-gem), [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase).

I'm using rspec for testing as describe in this [great tutorial](https://github.com/radar/guides/blob/master/gem-development.md).

My question is, how do I test my active record extension methods using Rspec, because as I can think, we are not using a DB to save records.

How can I write tests for these kind of gems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to have a look at acts_as_fu gem: https://github.com/nakajima/acts_as_fu.

Btw, you can use db in your rspec tests, but you don;t want to do this to test extensions.

Comment: @broistse thanks for your answer, currently I'm checking at 'acts_as_paranoid' which is again the same concept, but `test unit` though..

Answer (score 2):

if you didn't come up with a solution yet I was struggling with the same issues and and eventually came across [this tutorial](http://ryanbigg.com/2011/01/extending-active-record/). It uses a really solid approach and works like a dream.

Basically, it involves referencing an active record file in the test helper which your test itself creates from a schema and seed file.

This approach was surprisingly simple to implement and helped me better understand how ActiveRecord extensions worked. So cheers Ryan!

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks I ended up by creating the db schema before I do the tests (in spec_helper file). thanks for the reply