# Rails & Rspec: testing model with methods defined via module extending ActiveSupport::Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec

I have a module that defines a class method to dynamically define a series of instance methods based on values in given columns, roughly as follows:

**lib/active_record_extension.rb**

```
module ActiveRecordExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def define_some_methods(*attribute_names)
      # define some methods
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
```

**config/initializers/extensions.rb**

```
require 'active_record_extension.rb'
```

**app/models/my_model.rb**

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  define_some_methods :first_attribute, :second_attribute
end
```

This setup for adding a class method to ActiveRecord::Base is based on the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase).

This works beautifully in my Rails app and console, allowing me to define a variety of similar methods without cluttering up my model. However, it doesn't work at all in my rspec tests, which now all fail with `NoMethodError`s for calls to the dynamically defined methods.

How can I be sure this module (or just this method) is correctly included in my models while running rspec?

EDIT: Here is my **spec/spec_helper.rb**:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

#to test with sunspot
require 'sunspot/rails/spec_helper'
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ::Sunspot.session = ::Sunspot::Rails::StubSessionProxy.new(::Sunspot.session)
end

#adds devise and jasmine fixture test helpers
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"
end
```

Comment: Why not create a class in your test that includes your module and test against it?

Comment: Nm just re read, that would only be testing your module. Is it too much trouble to include ActiveRecordExtension for your models?

Comment: Would you share at least one test and the exact error your getting?

Answer (score 1):

I would propose an alternative way to solve the first problem which should also solve the current issue you're asking about. There's nothing ActiveSupport::Concern can do for you here that ruby can't so I would just stick with pure ruby and do:

```
module ActiveRecordExtension
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.class_eval do 
      extend ClassMethods
    end
  end 
 module ClassMethods
  def define_some_methods(*attribute_names)
   # define some methods
  end
 end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
```

If you have any questions about the included hook I can explain in more detail. You also don't need to require this file in an initializer(although when you make changes you will need to restart your local server)

Comment: The included hook gets around having to extend `ActiveSupport::Concern` nicely. However, I'm not sure how this helps load the needed class method in rspec. Whether I require the file in an initializer, in my model files, or in `spec_helper.rb`, the same `NoMethodError`s keep coming up in rpsec. Am I missing something?

Comment: Rspec is supposed to load your environment before running tests so my hunch is that it has something to do with your spec_helper.rb file. Can you edit the question and paste it in?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your solution but Concern comes to resolve some problems in it such as dependency, and make things simpler.