# Rails 4, better logging on rollback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-4, rollback

One of the things that is driving me crazy with Rails is that I'll see a `ROLLBACK` message in the console with no reason attached to the rollback. This often leads me into hunting for some validation error, but it would nice to have a more detailed message.

Is there anyway to enabled more detailed logging for db rollbacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [after_rollback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_rollback) callback.

Create a module called RollbackLogger and place it inside your app/concerns directory

```
module RollbackLogger
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_rollback :log_status, on: [:create, :update]
  end

  def log_status
    Rails.logger.info "Rollback caused by: #{self.errors.full_messages}"
  end
end
```

then include this module in every ActiveRecord model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RollbackLogger
end
```

Edit:

As [Mr. Damien Roche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1814021/damien-roche) suggests, you can create a new file inside the `config/initializers` directory and add the following line:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, RollbackLogger)
```

All models will include the `RollbackLogger` module automatically.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Rails, how would I do this across all models in a non-intrusive way?

Comment: @ChrisLedet see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase. With the concern in place, you can `ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, RollbackLogger)` to include in every model.