# Rails method for only returning a single record and throwing an exception when multiple are returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Django, the ORM has a function called [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) which is used to return only a single instance of a model. Specifically, it **raises an exception if multiple objects are returned when you only expected one**, so it's great for certain lookups (ie "Find the one article with this slug").

I haven't been able to find an analogous function in Rails/ActiveRecord that has the same behavior. So far, I've just been writing code like:

```
Model.where( ... ).first
```

But this has lead to silent bugs where multiple instances of an object were returned -- which is really a bad, ambiguous situation -- and we just grabbed the first one and carried on like everything was okay.

The [Active Record Query Interface guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object) lists 5 ways of retrieving a single object, with `find()` and `find_by()` looking the most promising, but neither of them raises an exception when multiple objects match the search criteria.

I know that I could just write `where()` and `find_by()` queries and check the number of objects returned myself, but this code appears everywhere in our codebase and I'd rather not add all that cruft. It also seems like such a generic, common need that I'd expect this to be baked into Rails/ActiveRecord somewhere.

Is there some function I'm missing that'd make it easier to catch these situations? We're using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.0 if it helps.

Comment: how about using `find_by!(..)`

Comment: @benchwarmer, find_by! only raises an exception if no records are found. The OP wanted a method that also raised an exception if more than one record was found.

Comment: Please note that the [`Person.where(first_name: 'Thomas').first`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first) is not the same as the [`[1, 2, 3].first`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-first) method on the `Array`class. It actually `LIMIT 1`s the SQL. See: `Todo.where(title: 'Any todo').first.to_sql # => SELECT "todos".* FROM "todos" WHERE "todos"."title" = 'Any todo' LIMIT 1` and  `Todo.where(title: 'Any todo').first(3).to_sql # => SELECT "todos".* FROM "todos" WHERE "todos"."title" = 'Any todo' ORDER BY "todos"."id" ASC LIMIT 3`

Comment: @ThomasKlemm good point. Adding the `.first` makes the SQL query grab only the first matching row from the DB, but even that is arbitrary since I don't have an `ORDER BY` clause. With the `LIMIT 1`, Rails would never know there were other potential matching records in the DB, so I'd have to do something like what Josh answered below. Maybe a `LIMIT 2` to ensure we don't somehow pull back tons of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a built in Active Record method that does what you ask but it wouldn't be hard to write your own.  Something like:

```
class YourModel
  def self.find_only_one_by_slug(slug)
    results = YourModel.where(slug: slug)
    if results.size > 1
      raise "There should only be one return value."
    else
      return results.first
    end
  end
end
```

I haven't tested the above code so there will most certainly be errors but you get the idea.  You could even take this a step farther and add a similar method to active record base that all of your models would have access to.

Comment: Thanks. I figured I'd probably end up having to roll my own if there isn't one built into ActiveRecord. I'll probably make a new base model that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` and then have all my app's models inherit from that, similar to how Rails sets up the `application_controller`.

Comment: Leaving "unaccepted" for now in case anyone else finds something. Will check back tomorrow.

Comment: @HartleyBrody You'll make your file easier if you just include a module into `ActiveRecord::Base` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase#answer-2329394). Just use unique method names, and don't monkey patch Rails or Ruby methods.

Comment: The problem here is that many times the developer will want to reduce their benchmark by cutting out the need to go grab the first hash in an array of hashes returned by AR. This is an overhead problem that I encounter quite a bit. If you benchmark a query where you accept the array of hashes that has one hash in it, and you also benchmark a method that looks for the first hash in that array, even if it is singular, you will notice a rather large increase in the real time spent to go inside that array and grab just one hash. It would be nice for AR to return a single record as a simple hash

Answer (score 9):

Rails 7.0 introduces [`find_sole_by`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_sole_by) (or `where(...).sole`) for this.

Seems to fit the bill perfectly:

> Finds the sole matching record. Raises `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if no record is found. Raises `ActiveRecord::SoleRecordExceeded` if more than one record is found.

Use case is simple:

```
Model.find_sole_by(conditions: 'here')
```

Comment: The [PR notes](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40768) even reference Django's `get()` method as a source of inspiration, which is exactly what the original question here was looking for.