# How to include order helper into different controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails application I have this:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  include ApplicationHelper

  def index
    @payments = current_user.projects.custom_order
  end

  ...

end
```

---

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def custom_order 
    order("name ASC")
  end

end
```

However, in my `index` view I get this error:

```
undefined method 'custom_order' for #<Class:0x007f8be606ff80>
```

How can this be done?

I would like to keep the `custom_order` method in a helper module because I am using it across various different controllers.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Okay . Just realized that it won't work. You cannot make order in helper method. As when you are doing .projects ... Then class is activerecords of class Project. Which is a model. Unless you use scope you cannot order any active record.

Comment: Try to extend active record base class to add custom order method . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase. Refer this ..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what you mean, but the right way is use model scopes:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...

  scope :custom_order, order('name ASC')

  #...
end
```

Comment: Thanks but my intention is to use that scope across various different controllers. And to be honest my `custom_order` method is a bit more dynamic than the one I posted above for reasons of brevity.

Comment: You can use that scope across various different controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Move it to application controller.and make it a helper method.

Or include application  helper module in application controller. So you will be able to access all application helper methods in all controllers.

Comment: I am doing that already. But it's not working and gives me the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Normally View Helpers are meant for rendering html based outputs, There you couldn't expect your model based queries.

Once you write a helper method in Application helper, It can be called in Any views.

Change your query like this

```
@payments = current_user.projects.order("name")
```

Or otherwise In your model Make it with scope.

```
scope :custom_order, order('name ASC')
```