# How to keep history in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are three questions here, all of them set in **bold**.

I have a personnel database where historical data is also stored.
Each table has two columns `start` and `stop` which indicate the period during which this fact is valid.

When any field of a record changes, a new record is created with `start=today`, and `stop=nil`,
and the old record is given a `stop=today-1` (or whatever the effective date of the change is instead of today).

When a record is to be deleted, instead of deleting, we simply set `stop=today`.

This way, it is easy to

- give a history of any employee
- give a snapshot of what things looked like on a particular date

Firstly this pattern seems common enough that probably I should not need to re-invent the wheel.
Yet in my search all I found were some gems called `auditable` or `papertrail`.
From a first glance, they did not seem to do what I want, but perhaps I am mistaken.
**Do you know of a gem that does something similar?**

If I don't find a solution, what is enough for my purposes is to have a few methods which works for all my models, like

```
def when(date)
    self.where("start <= ? and ? <= stop", ondate, ondate)
end
```

I thought about inheriting

```
class MyRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
    def when ...
    end
end
```

and having all my models inherit from `MyRecord`, but this broke everything. **Why?**

I could just add my methods to `ActiveRecord::Base`, but that seems wrong.
**What is the proper way to add a method to all models?**

### Answer

Parts 2 and 3 of this question have been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase). Since that contains Josh's answer (which I +1ed), as well as why inheriting from `MyRecord` doesn't work, I did not accept Josh's answer.

I still have not located a gem which maintains a good history, but two out of three ain't bad...

Comment: `having all my models inherit from MyRecord, but this broke everything.` what did broke?

Comment: The other way to do it is to put your common code in a module and include that in all your models that need it, but yeah, your inheritance solution should have worked.

Comment: @emaillenin "What did broke?" Now I don't remember so I tried to reproduce. First question: Where does this file my_record.rb go? In models it tries to find a table with that name. In helpers it still has the same complaint.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like an excellent opportunity to use an [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).  You could write something like:

**History.rb**

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module History
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    def self.when(date)
      self.where("start <= ? and ? <= stop", ondate, ondate)
    end
  end
end
```

**Your model**

```
class SomeClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  include History
end
```

You could then call `SomeClass.when(some_date_string)` on any models that you need to include history on.