# Extend Rails within Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-engines

I did a Rails extension as suggested by
[extending rails question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase) using Harish Shetty answer.

I like it so much I decided to use it in my Rails Engine.  Didn't quite work.

To make it work i place the file active_record_extensions in the Lib/[ENGINE] directory and added the Require active_record_extension to my engine.rb file.

This works, but I wonder if there's is a more proper way to do it.

Also. I ran into an Issue, (don't know if i'm allowed to piggyback a second question).

I have a Model called Translation.  When i use the extended class method with that model i invoke an error 'Circular dependency detected' with 
 raise "Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant #{qualified_name}"

I'm guessing that using the model extension exposed the name to something that doesn't like the fact that I used Translation.  (doesn't happen with the other models I have).  I get around it by not using the extend class method with that model.

Comment: Apparently i have a multithreading issue that showed up when i added the extension, probably unrelated.  So ignore the piggyback question about the circular dependencies