# Suppress Rails logging for specific ActiveRecord request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, logging

I know that Rails logging could be suppressed for entire controller using the `silencer` gem. But could an SQL output of some ActiveRecord request be suppressed individually by wrapping it into some statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Silence**

I don't have a specific answer for your question, but we use [`ActiveRecord::Base.logger.silence`](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler/blob/master/lib/exception_handler/parser.rb#L44) to silence the logger:

```
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger.silence do
        # your method here
    end
```

It's not for specific requests, but works for actions you may wish to stop logging. Perhaps you could extend `ActiveRecord::Base` to silence a specific method?

--

**Extending ActiveRecord**

Perhaps you could mix what I've described with extending ActiveRecord? The recommendation on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase) is to use an ActiveRecord concern.

I've never used one of these - can put together some code if you feel applicable

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
save_for_later = ActiveRecord::Base.logger
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil #turns off sql activity
... do stuff...
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = save_for_later
```

I've never done this in production code btw, only in rake tasks...