# Rails generate model + migration for subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a base model `MyAppRecordBase` which inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` and which all other models inherit from.
I used (in `config/environments/development.rb`) `config.generators.active_record[:parent] = 'MyAppRecordBase'` to make it default. How do I make `rails generate model XYZ` to create a migration file for new models (it do all exept creating migration file..)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after searching for solutions, I used [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2329394/3385098) by @HarishShetty, And it solve it.

Comment: I believe the issue you were facing is that when you subclass a model in rails that by default it will use the parent class's database tables.  Therefore the generator doesn't think that it needs to create the migration file.

Answer (score 1):

try scaffolding:

rails g scaffold MODEL_NAME

Comment: Thanks, @AhmedSamirShahin, it did the job, But I don`t want it to generate the all scaffold files..