# How do I add a method to ActiveRecord::Batches?

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

I was trying to add my custom implementation for `ActiveRecords`s `find_in_batches` method. First, I tried to monkeypatch the corresponding module:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Batches
    def find_in_batches2
    end
  end
end

Task.find_in_batches2 do |group|
end
```

But `ruby` said:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_in_batches2' for Task (call 'Task.connection' to establish a connection):Class
/home/yuri/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
/srv/http/tm/Rakefile:15:in `<top (required)>'
/home/yuri/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/yuri/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/yuri/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/yuri/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/yuri/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/yuri/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/yuri/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/yuri/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
```

Then I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2329394/52499), to no avail. What am I doing wrong and why is it so hard?

Comment: You have not described your intentions or any logic to follow. I have found altering ActiveRecord to be a daunting task at times but without any concept of what you are intending to do we cannot help very much

Comment: @engineersmnky I want to iterate over records in batches in descending order if that's what you'd like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
ActiveRecord::Batches.module_eval do
  def find_in_batches2
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Querying.module_eval do
  delegate :find_in_batches2, :to => :all
end
```

Don't forget to implement `find_in_batches2`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's wrong with my solution, and what exactly does your code, why is it as it is?