# extending class with modules containing class methods of the same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, mixins

I extended my ActiveRecord class by the notable pattern described [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase). 
I can't find a way to safely make my new included class method (`extend_with_mod_a` and `extend_with_mod_b`) call their own class method (`bar`)

```rb
require 'active_record'

module ModA
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods

    def extend_with_mod_a
      puts "extending #{self} with ModA"
      bar
    end

    def bar
      puts "this is method bar of ModA"
    end

  end

end


module ModB
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods

    def extend_with_mod_b
      puts "extending #{self} with ModB"
      bar
    end

    def bar
      puts "this is method bar of ModB"
    end

  end

end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ModA
ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ModB

class TestModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend_with_mod_a
  extend_with_mod_b

end
```

Output is

```
extending with ModA
this is method bar of ModB
extending with ModB
this is method bar of ModB
```

Of course which bar method gets called depends on ActiveRecord include calls order. I would like to use something like `ModA::ClassMethods.bar` in `extend_with_mod_a` method definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module ModA
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def bar
      puts "this is method bar of ModA"
    end

    # grab UnboundMethod of ModA::ClassMethods::bar
    a_bar = instance_method(:bar)

    # using define_method to capture a_bar
    define_method :extend_with_mod_a do
      puts "extending #{self} with ModA"
      # invoke ModA::ClassMethods::bar properly bound to the class being extended/included with ModA
      a_bar.bind(self).call
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `:prepend` your module.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send :prepend, ExtModule
```

Comment: Question updated and :prepend tried.. not working. thx anyway