# Rails, undefined method in Class but method is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to solve a strange issue.
I'm extending ActiveRecord using a module.

```
module StringyAssociationIds

  def stringy_ids(association)
    define_method("stringy_#{association}_ids=") do |comma_seperated_ids|
      self.send("#{association}_ids=", comma_seperated_ids.to_s.split(","))
    end

    define_method("stringy_#{association}_ids") do
      send("#{association}_ids").join(",")
    end
  end

end

ActiveRecord::Base.extend(StringyAssociationIds)
```

I have a class "Gate" where I have an association.

```
class Gate < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Productable
  stringy_ids :product
end
```

The association is defined with a join table:

```
module Productable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :productable_products, as: :productable
    has_many :products, through: :productable_products
  end

end
```

When I try to create a new Gate I have an error:

```
undefined method `stringy_ids' for #<Class:0x007f91e12bb7e8>
```

Where is my fault?

Edit: I try also to add an extension inside the lib directory (autoloaded by application.rb)

```
module ActiveRecordExtension

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def stringy_ids(association)
    define_method("stringy_#{association}_ids=") do |comma_seperated_ids|
      self.send("#{association}_ids=", comma_seperated_ids.to_s.split(","))
    end

    define_method("stringy_#{association}_ids") do
      send("#{association}_ids").join(",")
    end
  end

end

# include the extension 
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
```

I try also in console:

```
ActiveRecordExtension.instance_methods
 => [:stringy_ids]
```

So my extension is loaded...

Comment: It looks like `ActiveRecord::Base` is not extended with your `StringyAssociationIds` module *before* `Gate` class definition. `string_ids` is invoked immediately after source parsed, before any instantiation. Either make sure proper loading order, ie `Gate` processed afterwards, or move `stringy_ids` into initializer. Btw. why are you polluting Activerecord and not Gate class directly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StringyAssociationIds` is not extended.
Actually, `ActiveRecord::Base.extend(StringyAssociationIds)` does not run. Move this code in `config/initializer`

Comment: I already try to move it. My lib directory is autoloaded on application start.

Comment: Do you mean your lib directory is added to `config.autoload_pathes`?

Comment: When you add in autoload_path it is not actually run at start. It run when module is called firsttime. I think systme does not read ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension) or ActiveRecord::Base.extend(StringyAssociationIds) line. try in console execute 'ActiveRecord::Base.extend(StringyAssociationIds)' and call Gate

Comment: I try to move in initializer... in console

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
ActiveRecordExtension.instance_methods
 => [:stringy_ids]

But Gate.new return me error "undefined method"

Comment: not 'include' maybe 'extend' 'stringy_ids=' is class method

Answer (score 3):

Your class method `stringy_ids` is defined on `ActiveRecord::Base`, not `Gate`. Unlike instance methods, class methods are not inherited because the singleton class of `Gate` is not a subclass of the singleton class of `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Comment: I copied the code inside my class and I receive the same error. I'm following this [gist](https://gist.github.com/smoil/5061616)

Comment: I try also in another way, following [this so answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase). Doesn't work.