# Where to properly outsource model code in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In a model of mine I'm using the bing translator gem for automatic translation of a model attribute via a `after_create` callback:

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :auto_translate

  ....

  # AUTO_TRANSLATE STUFF
  def initialize_bing_translator(bing_id, bing_secret)
    t = BingTranslator.new(bing_id, bing_secret)
    <do other stuff>
  end

  def auto_translate
    <do stuff>
  end

  <further auto_translate methods>
```

The whole bunch of functions seems to bloat the model code a little so I want to put it into some extra module. **Where** exactly shall I place the .rb-file? Is this a use-case for a concern (a concept I did not fully understood)? Is it better to define a seperate module in the model file itself or to place it in `/lib/user_modules/`? Is there sth like a rule-of-thumb? The information available on the web are confusing me a little and I'd be glad if someone could shed some light on that issue for me!

Comment: Will [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase) question help?

Comment: for me it can be resided in two places: 1. `lib/models/...` and 2. `app/models/concern`. the modules from both places should be explicitly included/extended to the model

Comment: Can you explain why you do it this way? The proposal down below for example is somehow different (put model related stuff in a sub-folder)

Answer (score 1):

I started putting stuff like that in subfolders of `models` and namespacing things accordingly. In your specific case I'd put it in something like `models/place/translator.rb` (or similar) and call the class `Place::Translator`.

If you just want a sort of logical separation but will not use the same functionality elsewhere you can use [concerning](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/Module/Concerning.html) instead of a separate concern.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options and most of them are primarily opinion-based. It depends on if you plan to reuse that class, how complex your application already is and if the new class has any external dependency.

I would think about: create your own gem, add to `app/models`, add a new `app/translators` directory, perhaps in `lib`...