# Rails - include a module without using the word include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, audit

I noticed in the audited gem you can do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # All fields
  # audited

  # Single field
  # audited only: :name

  # Multiple fields
  # audited only: [:name, :address]
```

I'm trying to replicate this behaviour with not much luck, I'm using instructions here to extend my module:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9200191/312342

here is my class:

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  audited only: :name
end
```

My module:

```
module Audited
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    
    def ClassMethods
      def audited(options = {})
        class_attribute :audited_options
        self.audited_options = options
        after_save :audit
      end
    end

    def audit
      puts self.changed_attributes
      puts self.audited_options
    end
end

::ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, Audited)
```

Error I'm getting (only on the first load, then error stops, but module still does not output.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `audited' for #<Class:0x00007fae51b15ab0>):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module is included into `ActiveRecord::Base` only when the file is executed. Assuming you're using rails autoloading, it's only executed when `Audited` is called.

You'll need to require the file or execute `::ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, Audited)`  somewhere in your load process (initializer).