# rails get all associated classes of a polymorphic class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic association like so (adapted from guides.rubyonrails.com):

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable

  has_many :employees
end
```

Is there a way to get all of the possible :imageable_types **only given the Picture model**?

For example to get the class of has_many :quotes in the Product model, you would do:

```
Product.reflect_on_association(:employees).klass
```

to get: # => Employee

Now I want to do something similar:

```
Picture.reflect_on_association(:imageable).klass
```

This obviously throws an exception, but I want to get something like: # => [Employee, Product]

Is there a way to do this? (Without trying out all models to see if they contain has_many :pictures)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this without looking at all the models, so I just adapted this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2315469/1440599