# Getting a list of valid models for a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, polymorphic-associations

Taking the polymorphic associations example from [rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) and using the models below:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

How do I go about finding the valid `imageable_type`s?

E.g. so that it'd return: `[:employee, :product]`

Comment: There is this answer from 6 years ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315239/finding-all-by-polymorphic-type-in-rails/2315469#2315469. What is does it loops over every model inside your project and  using method reflect_on_all_associations looks for has_many or has_one associations.

Answer (score 0):

My question would be why do you need this? I'm not totally sure, but I think you may be looking for:

```
Picture.select(:imageable_type).distinct.pluck(:imageable_type)
```

Comment: Your question is a good question... Maybe I'm setting up my models wrong... About your solution, it won't work for me because that would only return the `:imageable_type`s that were in use... I'm looking for _ALL_ types, whether in use, or _could_ be used.

Ok, so like I said, maybe my models are set up wrong. In reality, what I have is a base `Report` which is polymorphic, and then concrete _reports_ (e.g. `ReportA`, `ReportB`, `ReportC`, etc.). What I want is the list of `Report*` that is defined so I can create a dropdown that selects the appropriate concrete report.